# what does '%0*x' % (int1, int2) syntax do in python?

Tags: python, string, string-interpolation

I know it is string interpolation, but I can't understand what is the exact meaning. It seems it convert int2 to hexadecimal as a string(I see this behavior in debugging) but what is the int1 role? (I guess it is the size of hexadecimal)
can anybody explain in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` means to get the field width from the corresponding argument, rather than hard-coding it into the format string (e.g. `%08x` means to print 8 hex digits). So `int1` specifies the number of digits to print.

The `0` before the field width means to pad the output with zeroes rather than spaces.

Comment: so 0 after % means specifying the size. Am I correct?

Comment: If it is, can I use '%0*s' % (10,string) for interpolation on the strings?

Comment: The number after the percent sign specifies the field width. Leading the number with a zero specifies that the field is to be padded with zeroes instead of spaces. This is fully described in the manual: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting